# How to hide mouse pointer in GTK C

Tags: c, gtk, mouse

I have an application which I have made using gtk and c. It runs on full screen mode and displays data on a label. I need to hide the mouse pointer as soon as the application starts and then unhide it when the application stops.

How to do it.

This is my main window:

```
GtkWidget *window = NULL;

window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);  
gtk_widget_set_size_request((window),640,480);  
gtk_widget_realize (window);
gtk_window_fullscreen((GtkWindow*)window);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

```
GdkCursor* Cursor = gdk_cursor_new(GDK_BLANK_CURSOR);
GdkWindow* win = gtk_widget_get_window((window));
gdk_window_set_cursor((win),Cursor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Phew, that was a rabbit hole of deprecation!

It seems, from a quick skim of the docs, that the current best bet is the [`gdk_seat_grab()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkSeat.html#gdk-seat-grab) function. It has a bunch of arguments, one of them is a `GdkCursor *`. The cursor is set while the grab is active.

You should be able to use [`gdk_cursor_new_for_display()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-for-display) with `GDK_BLANK_CURSOR` to get a blank cursor to use.

You can get the default display using the [`gdk_display_get_default()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkDisplay.html#gdk-display-get-default) function. This is usually enough unless you need to think about multi-display support; anyway this should get you started with the APIs.

Comment: Thank You. Can you give an example as I am confused with the display `GdkDisplay *display`. What to use in case of display.?

Comment: I used it like `gdk_cursor_new_for_display(gdk_display_get_default(),GDK_BLANK_CURSOR);` but it didnt hide the mouse pointer

Comment: @SAndrew Huh? You are not calling `gdk_seat_grab()`? That's the function that needs to the blank cursor and actually *sets* it, otherwise you just have a blank cursor, that won't get just because you created it.

Comment: Can you pls give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need `gdk_seat_grab()`; what you really want is `gdk_window_set_cursor()`. And for using an invisible cursor, you can use `gdk_cursor_new_from_name()` to load the `"none"` cursor, which is typically handled explicitly by GDK backend implementations to return a blank cursor. [The Cursors example in gtk3-demo gives you an example of how to use it.](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo/cursors.c?h=gtk-3-22)

Noote that this means if GTK+ ever unrealizes your window for any reason, you'll ahve to reset your cursor. So you may want to connect to the two realization signals to do the assignment.