# How do I hide the mouse cursor and set its position in gtk3?

Tags: c, cursor, gtk, mouse, gtk3

I am trying to make a game where you move the mouse to change your view but you cannot see the mouse and the mouse needs to be stuck in the center, similar to in minecraft. In fact, this IS for my own personal knockoff of Minecraft. I need to hide cursor, and constantly setting the position of the cursor to the center. BUT I still need to track mouse movement, so I can change the view accordingly. These are my codes for how to find the center of the window.

```
int CenterY = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(Window)/2;
int CenterX = gtk_widget_get_allocated_Width(Window)/2;
```

*How shall I proceed?*

Comment: Can you do it by changing the cursor to a fully transparent background icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide mouse pointer in GTK C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453139/how-to-hide-mouse-pointer-in-gtk-c)

Comment: Love the `gdk_cursor_new(GDK_BLANK_CURSOR);`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a game toolkit for making a Minecraft clone. GTK might not be the right tool for this job.

Comment: @ptomato I beg to differ, as cairo (which in my understanding is part of gtk) can draw shapes, including quadriladerals and each minecraft pixel in the game could be a quadriladeral. Other tools would be easier, yes, but I can make GTK work.

Comment: Why do you need to set it's position? Would grabbing the pointer inside the window work for you?