# How to always hide mouse cursor in Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm currently working on a side project, a Gtkmm app running on a Raspberry Pi that only uses keyboard shortcuts. In order to make it a little bit cleaner I would like to hide the mouse cursor permanently. Is there a way to do this ? My research didn't lead to anything, as it looks like Gtkmm disappeared from the forums since Gtk+ exists...

Comment: There must be a way to set the mouse cursor and you could make it all transparent.

Comment: yeah that really sounds good ! thanks I'll check that tomorrow

Comment: You might refer to the following answer [Blank Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453139/how-to-hide-mouse-pointer-in-gtk-c).  It was for a C program, but it should be straight forward to derive the C++ code.